# Why does Postgres start enforcing ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock for ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN statements starting 9.4?

Tags: database, postgresql

My original understanding for `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` in postgres is that if you just add a simple new column (i.e. no default value, no indexing, no non-null validation etc.) then there's no locking.

However starting from 9.4 this no longer seems to be true:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-altertable.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html

In the 9.4 documentation it says

> An ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock is held unless explicitly noted. When
>   multiple subcommands are listed, the lock held will be the strictest
>   one required from any subcommand.

while there was no such thing in 9.3.

In practice, 9.4 does seem more likely to trigger deadlock when the table has heavy traffic - not exactly sure why this is the case though. Theory is the transaction is implicitly holding a `ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table and then it gets escalated to `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` when the statement gets executed but again it's just a theory.

Question is: what changed the design and what's the correct way to add a column today for tables with high traffic?

Comment: Why would that increase the likelihood of a **deadlock**? Are you using multiple transactions that run ALTER TABLE statements on multiple tables in different order? It might increase lock waits, but I fail to see how this could lead to deadlocks.

Comment: @NSF Might I ask what was the basis of this question, did you experience deadlocks, and in that case, did you ever figure out why?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested with PostgreSQL 9.2, and it takes an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock as it should.

The lock will only be held for a short duration, but if there is a lot of concurrent activity (in particular long operations), there could be a noticable hang with transactions piling up behind the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock request that is waiting for a long transaction to finish.

The difference in the documentation is due to PostgreSQL commit [e5550d5fec66aa74caad1f79b79826ec64898688](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=e5550d5fec66aa74caad1f79b79826ec64898688) which improved the documentation while, ironically, *reducing* the lock level required by certain `ALTER TABLE` subcommands.

It is an ongoing effort to reduce the number and severity of locks in PostgreSQL wherever possible.